# How do I use JDBCOperations to query a database table one row at a time, and return void, yet construct a hashmap based on values?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Whenever I implement a RowMapper it always expects some sort of domain object that it can construct an object out of. Is this mandatory? I have a table of about 10,000 rows. The end goal is to iterate each of those rows and create a HashMap of certain column values that will be passed to another service one at a time.

**I do not want to create and return 10,000 useless objects in Java memory just to go back and construct the hashmaps after the fact. I want to construct the hashmaps on the fly with the row's data passed through the function, and then move to the next row, basically throwing away the previous row's data.**

My starting point is that I have a reference to a jdbcOperations (so I can access the methods such as query). Now that I have access to this object, what would be the best way to literally go one by one in a 10,000 row table, and on *EACH* row, construct a HashMap using the ResultSet values?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want instead of `RowMapper` which is designed to map each row to an object, you want a `ResultSetExtractor` which will return a single object.

Without seeing your code it's hard to be concrete but something like the following (not tested):

```
Map<Whatever, Whatever> finalMap = jdbcOperations.query(sql, args, new ResultSetExtractor() {
   Map<Whatever, Whatever> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
       Map<Whatever, Whatever> map = new HashMap<>();
       while (rs.next()) {
           // put stuff into your map

       }
       return map;
   }  
});
```

Comment: I just want to literally iterate each row on the database table, construct a hashmap<String, Object> out of the resultset data for each row.

Comment: Are you saying that for each row you want to construct a hashmap and then call another object with that data? In effect you don't need to return anything from your operation?

Comment: yes. I found the answer on another thread the solution is to not use RowMapper, but instead to use a RowCallbackHandler.